# Autohotkey: AlwaysOnTop, On, Run ahk_class SunAwtDialog

Tags: autohotkey

i want "Run ahk_class SunAwtDialog" window stayAlwaysOnTop. This time its not working. its working with other windows for e.g. google chrom. Here is the code:

```
CoordMode,Pixel
CoordMode,Screen
CoordMode,Mouse
run_Win = Run ahk_class SunAwtDialog
SetTitleMatchMode,1
IfWinNotExist,%run_Win% 
{
   MsgBox,:( Oops 
   Reload
}
SetTitleMatchMode,2
WinSet , AlwaysOnTop , Off , SciTE4AutoHotkey
SetTitleMatchMode,1
WinSet , AlwaysOnTop , On , %run_Win% ; dont work. window stays behind
WinGetPos,x,y,w,h,%run_Win%
MouseGetPos,xM,yM
MouseMove,% x, % y , 10 ; works: mouse is moving to left top of the window
Sleep,500
MouseMove,% xM, % yM , 10 ; works: restore mouse pos
MsgBox, , endOfProgramm1, endOfProgramm2 , 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code snippet

```
run_Win = Run ahk_class SunAwtDialog
SetTitleMatchMode,1
IfWinNotExist,%run_Win%
```

Could be translated to

```
SetTitleMatchMode,1
IfWinNotExist,Run ahk_class SunAwtDialog
```

. `IfWinNotExist, Run ahk_class ...` does not make any sense. Remove the `run` in the contents of your`run_Win` variable.

(See [WinTitle](http://ahkscript.org/docs/misc/WinTitle.htm) for information on how to catch the right window)

Comment: When I teach my computer science students, I encourage them to save due to higher flexibility, names and arguments as possible in variables. Parameter settings can be changed quickly. Again, there was useful. The test was quickly converted to other types of windows. As already mentioned, it worked, for example with Goole Chrome.

Comment: in this context, it is not a command but a window name. I therefore using "run" as a window name.

Comment: ahk_classes are no window names, they are one specific string which identify a window. if you start `ifwinnotexist` with `ahk_class`, then you might only state the ahk_class, and nothing else. you're mixing up window title and window ahk class. or do you mean that your window is called "Run ahk_class SunAwtDialog"? what window would ever be called like that??

Comment: it moves to the left top oft the window. means it finds it. but it not set it on top.  my question was. why it happens only with this window. you see it could be find. and it works with other windows. i seems to me there is something special with some java windows.

Comment: WorkAround: 

    SetTitleMatchMode,2
    WinSet , AlwaysOnTop , on , PhpStorm 9.0 ahk_class SunAwtFrame 

includes "Run ahk_class SunAwtDialog".

to set only the dialog - window alone to put on-top window i did not succeed.